# Make movable piece with Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am a complete beginner in JavaScript/HTML. I have created a canvas in JavaScript where I've drawn a chessboard and I also have a file with a bunch of images of chess pieces. At this point, I would like to take the pieces from my image file and load them onto the board, where they can be movable pieces that I can track and do stuff with JavaScript.

I tried loading all the images onto the canvas using JavaScript like so (small snippet):

```
function drawPieces() {
  let white_pawn = new Image()
  white_pawn.src = 'Pieces/White_Pawn.png'
  white_pawn.onload = function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      ctx.drawImage(white_pawn, i * size, 6 * size, size, size)
    }
  }
  let white_king = new Image()
  white_king.src = 'Pieces/White_King.png'
  white_king.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(white_king, 4 * size, 7 * size, size, size)
  }
  ...
}
```

but I cannot have the user interact with this board. I could redraw the board every time I detect a mouse click on a certain x-y coordinate, but that is not what I want.

I could also load the images through HTML, but I am finding it difficult to change the positioning of the images in JavaScript.

My question is what is the best approach to creating a chessboard with interactible pieces that allows me to access the pieces through JavaScript easily? Thank you.

Comment: How exactly do you want the users to interact with your chess board?

Comment: @N3R4ZZuRR0 Click a piece and be able to drag it to the square you want or click a piece and click another square and have it move there.

Comment: Have you tried achieving this? I mean, can you share some more code?

Comment: I have tried using HTML image elements but cannot figure out how to position them using JavaScript, and don't know any alternatives, which is what I was asking about.

Comment: Well, you can use img elements too for this purpose. IMO, using a canvas would be better. Also, you should consider using Event Listeners (like `mousedown` and `mousemove`) for selecting and dragging pieces.

Comment: @N3R4ZZuRR0 From what I read, once you draw an image on a canvas, you can no longer remove that image without redrawing the entire canvas again. I do not want to do that because I'd like to add lots of animations in the future, which would be intensive.

Comment: How much intensive could your animations be? Because, canvas can handle animations pretty well using `requestAnimationFrame` if the code is optimized to maintain a good FPS rate if possible.

Comment: @N3R4ZZuRR0 I see, I thought it would be a lot harder considering it would be loading not only 64 rectangles but 32 images 60 times a second ideally. If that is not the case, then I guess drawing images is fine too!

Comment: You can also leave the chess board static as an image or another canvas layered behind the main canvas to minimize the "things being done per frame". And, your main canvas would be able to handle those 32 images without any lag I suppose.